firewalld different rules for different interfaces
running RHEL 8.9, with firewalld is there a way to have a specific /etc/firewalld/zones/mycustom.rules file for different network interfaces?
For example, I have a quad-port nic in a server, doing ifconfig shows the ports and this is what I want to happen:

eno100 use /etc/firewalld/zones/eno100.xml
eno99 use /etc/firewalld/zone/eno99.xml

is there  a way to do that and if so how?
here is a sample of my eno99.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>eno99</short>
  <description>eno99</description>
  <interface name="eno99"/>

# sshd
  <port protocol="tcp" port="22"/>

# samba
#  <port protocol="tcp" port="445"/>

# nfs
  <port protocol="tcp" port="2049"/>

</zone>

For eno100, I want SSH and SAMBA open, but not NFS.  And for eno99 I want SSH and NFS open but not SAMBA.  Is it just a matter of modifying the "interface" line in the xml file?
What commands (firewall-cmd ?) can I do to validate my firewalld setup is as expected?
